# Removing a random choice from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, text

So I am building a date generator for my girlfriend and I can't seem the program to remove the date from the sample pool once it has been selected. `dateChoice()` does the actual selecting of the date which works find, but the`dateRemover()` doesn't seem to work. I've read up on a bunch of .txt writing and reading and I can't seem to get this to work. Thanks!

```
import random

#Imports date list
dateList = open("file", 'r+')
dates = dateList.readlines()
line = "-----------------------------------------"
choice = ""
date = ""

#Selects a Date
def dateChoice():
    date = random.choice(dates)
    print("Your date is: {}".format(date)

#Removes date from list
def dateRemover():
    choice = input("Would you like to remove the date from the list?")
    if str.upper(choice) in ["Y", "YES"]:
        print(line)
        dateList.seek(0)
        for i in dates:
            if i != date:
                dateList.write(i)
        dateList.truncate()
        print("All is done")
    elif str.upper(choice) in ["N", "NO"]:
        print(line)
        print("Okay. your date is still in the system!")
    else:
        print(line)
        print("Please answer with either Yes or No")
        dateRemover()


#Start of program
def start():
    dateChoice()
    dateRemover()

#Runs programs
start()
```

Comment: You have created in "dateChoice" a local variable "date" which shadows the global one and is lost on function exit. Declare it as "global" at beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Butscher's comment is correct, like this:

```
#Selects a Date
def dateChoice():
    global date
    date = random.choice(dates)
    print("Your date is: {}".format(date))
```

Also, you were missing a closing right parenthesis on the print